# Regex in Notepad++ to remove certain CRLFs

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given this sample data:

```
00-1234T|`CRLF`
Data|Commments|`CRLF`
12-3456|Some data|Notes|`CRLF`
65-8436ZZ|Data|`CRLF`
|`CRLF`
45-4576AA|Some data|Comments|`CRLF`
98-4392REV|Data|`CRLF`
|`CRLF`
00-5432|Some Data|Some Comments|
```

(I added the "`CRLF`"s to each line to more clearly illustrate what is there and what needs to be replaced)

Each record should only have three pipes in a line, with a `CRLF` after the third pipe. So lines 1, 4, and 7 (pre-find/replace) need to be fixed, which means any `CRLF`s before the third pipe needs to be replaced with a "placeholder", which will be "#CRLF#".

The closest I've been able to come up with is `^((?:[^\v|]*\|){3})(.+)`, which will match (highlight) lines 3 & 4, 6 & 7, and 9 & 10. My expectation (requirement) is to find the `CRLF`s in lines 2, 5, & 8 and replace those with "#CRLF#".

**[UPDATE]**

After sleeping on this question, I woke up realizing that, for the purpose of more accurately finding the beginning of a given record - whether on one line or multiple - I should add that the first column will **always** start with the pattern `[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` and **possibly** have up to three alphanumeric characters after that.

I modified the sample data above to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d\d-\d{4}\w{0,3}\|)`
- Replace with: `#CRLF#`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n), 
                     if you want to match only windows EOL, use \r\n
(?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
    \d\d-\d{4}      # 2 digit dash 4 digit
    \w{0,3}         # word character from 0 upto 3
    \|              # a pipe
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: To make sure it worked, I entered the Find/Replace settings and clicked "Find next", but when it highlighted the `CRLF` on the first line and I clicked Replace, the `CRLF` wasn't replaced, the highlight just went to the next `CRLF`. But when I clicked Replace All, it worked. So it works, but I'm working with a HUGE file (160k+ lines before the `CFLR`s are cleaned up) and I'd rather step through a few times until I make sure it's working as needed. Any idea why that behaved like that?

Comment: Addition to above: @sln's worked when I clicked Find Next then Replace, Find Next, Replace, etc, etc

Comment: @marky: I've seen this strange behaviour some times, I don't know why, may be a bug in Notepad++!

Comment: @marky: If your file is very big, you'd better to write a script. Or, test my regex with a small part of your file and if it works fine, do the replacement for the whole  file.

Comment: @marky: According to your edit, use Find: `\R(?!\d\d-\d{4}\w{0,3}\|)` ; Replace: `#CRLF#`, this is working strep by step as well as replace all.

Comment: Your new code worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.
The regex just captures the parts between pipes then re-writes on the substitution.
Any CRLF's are not captured and get stripped out.
But this is very simplistic and may need to change if your input is any more complex.

```
 (?m)^([^|\r\n]*)[\r\n]*\|[\r\n]*([^|\r\n]*)[\r\n]*\|[\r\n]*([^|\r\n]*)[\r\n]*\|[\r\n]*
```

Replace using:  `$1|$2|$3|\n`

https://regex101.com/r/WzDLwf/1

**updated answer**

To answer your updated question, if you need to make it like mail merge,
it could also be done like this (as an alternative to Toto's method).

```
(?m)
(?:
   ^ \d{2} - \d{4} [^|\r\n]* \| 
 | \G 
)
(?: [^|\r\n]* \| )*
\K 
[\r\n]+ (?! [\r\n]* (?: ^ \d{2} - \d{4} | $ ) )
```

https://regex101.com/r/qK4SJP/1

Comment: This correctly finds the "orphan" `CFLF`s, but it only removes it and gets each record on a single line. I need to retain those with placeholders (hence the replace with #CRLF#) so they can be put back later. How would I add in "#CRLF#" to your Replace code?

Comment: @marky - sure it can be done like that, see the update posting. Gives a little more record validation if needed.